# How to: Remove an item from a List<string>

Tags: c#, string, list, listview, selecteditem

**How to: Remove an item from a List**

I have got the following code snippet...

```
companies.Remove(listView_Test.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

There is a `listView` that contains (let's say) 3 items without a name, just with a `Content` of "A", "B" and "C". Now when I select an item of that `listView`, I secondly click on a button, which runs my method containing `Remove()`/`RemoveAt()`. Now I want to delete the line of the `List<string> myList` where the line is same to the `Content` of the selected item.

**Edit:** Solution by *Flow Flow OverFlow*

```
int index = companies.IndexOf(companyContent);
companies.RemoveAt(index);
```

Comment: Call the .RemoveAt method, followed by passing the index of item you wanna remove as an argument

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are trying to delete?

Comment: you need to use Remove function and pass in a predicate. Something like x => x.Text == listView_Test.SElectedItem.ToString(). Notice this code will probably not work (thats why i didn't put it as an answer) it should just leed you in the right direction. I don't have the time to post a full answer now, sorry

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to get the index of the object you wanna remove from the list, then you can:

```
//Assuming companies is a list 
companies.RemoveAt(i);
```

To get the index of the item you can use :

```
companies.IndexOf("Item");
```

or use a for loop with conditional statements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < companies.Count; i++) {
   // if it is List<String>
   if (companies[i].Equals("Something")) {
         companies.RemoveAt(i);   
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "index of the object"? I do not know its position if you mean that. It is somewhere in the `List<string>`, I just know the "name". It is like "delete * from myList where `Content` = 'Hello World'".

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'd like to do.

Comment: If you remove an item during the iterations the list size/count changes and the `i < companies.Count` condition doesn't guarantee to check all the list. Please try with a list of two removable items: `{"Something","Something"}`

Comment: @Tobia So, would it be better to loop through the list in backward order, like `for (int i=(companies.Count-1); i>=0; i--)`?

Comment: Yes, it can be a solution.

Answer (score 8):

You could either remove the item by its known position or by the contents in the item.

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<Object> items = new List<Object>();
    items.Add("test1");
    items.Add("test2");
    items.Add("test3");

foreach(var a in items)
    Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("--");

items.RemoveAt(1); // remove object at position 1, in this case "test2"

foreach(var a in items)
    Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("--");

items.RemoveAll(x => ((string) x) == "test1"); // LAMBDA query to remove by a condition

foreach(var a in items)
    Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
}
```

Output

```
test1
test2
test3
--
test1
test3
--
test3
```

Comment: I think you have to cover RemoveRange also

Answer (score 1):

```
public int FindItem(List<string> haystack, string needle)
{ for (int i = 0; i < haystack.Count; i++) 
      if (haystack[i] == needle) return i;
  return -1;
}


try {
     companies.Remove(FindItem(companies, listView_Test.SelectedItem.ToString() ) );
    } catch {  /* not found, no problem.. */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

I really can't understand what your question is but here are some references that might help you:

See ListViewItem's Text property if your problem relates to accessing the text of the currently selected list view item:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.text(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

See List.Remove if your problem relates to removing elements from a generic List: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)